# I need xcopy to retain the parent folder

Tags: xcopy, robocopy

On a mapped network drive R: there are multiple folders that I have been asked to copy using xcopy to preserve meta-data to a different target directory on another mapped network drive "T:\username\Destination"

**Examples:**
R:\name1\name2\Name3\Target1*.*
R:\name1\Name2\Target2*.*

Since there are multiple source directories, I need to preserve their folder names when copied into the destination folder.

**Example:**
T:\Username\Destination\Target1*.*
T:\Username\Destination\Target2*.*

no matter what switches I use with the xcopy command  The result I always get is:
T:\Username\Destination(all of the files WITHIN Target1)

Which is not what I want.

I have not been able to use robocopy for the same reason.

I know about specifying the folder name in the destination of the xcopy command, but that won't work because it will create a new folder with new meta-data and not use the meta-data of the source folder.

Thank you for your assitance

Comment: This is probably where you need to reach out to PowerShell tools; this might not be possible with a cmd.exe one-liner.